# Publishing multifile org-mode projects

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I would like to use org-mode to maintain a simple website that is a collection of notes organized by topic.  I understasnd the basics of publishing -- i.e., using `C-x C-e P p` to publish all the files in the current project -- but these files are all independent of one another and I have to manually link with `[[file:nexttopic.org][the next topic]]` to make the different topics "aware" of one another.

Is there a better way to make org-mode aware of the structure of the topics and have it automatically generate a single page that is a table of contents as well as link to the next/previous topics?

Comment: Try asking on the oldschool org-mode mailing list at [https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/emacs-orgmode](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/emacs-orgmode) The org-mode developers, and many others with deep knowledge of both org-mode's out-of-box capabilities and its deep structure, answer questions like yours in depth and detail regularly.

Comment: True. But here you can get good answers too. And the Org maintainers are probably happy if they don't have to provide all the help themselves. By the way, you should have used a comment instead of an answer to provide this hint. Well actually you can't because you don't have enough reputation yet. But once you do have enough reputation, then use comments.

Comment: Agreed, and after a week's time no one has responded, and as I haven't seen the question author on the list, thought he might be unaware of it. Thanks for noticing that the reason I didn't comment was my low reputation.

Comment: Will a sitemap work?  Try adding [`:auto-sitemap t`](http://orgmode.org/manual/Sitemap.html#Sitemap) to your project alist?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/7241)